# How to make Xbox joypad work with Bastion?

Tags: games, mono

I have an XBox joypad:

> Bus 005 Device 004: ID 045e:0289 Microsoft Corp. Xbox Controller S

When I start Bastion from the terminal the following is output:

> Number of joysticks: 1
>
> Number of buttons for joystick: 0 - 10
>
> Number of axes for joystick: 0 - 6
>
> Number of PovHats for joystick: 0 - 1

When I load up the game it displays a message "press any key" and at this point, if I press a button on the joypad it advances to the main menu. However, the up/down/left/right controls do not work and the button will not operate the menu. When I enter the control configuration, the joypad section is disabled and displays a message "joypad not detected." If I enter the control customization and try to reconfigure one of the controls, noises can be heard when pressing joypad buttons, but the input is otherwise ignored.

---

Further information which may or may not be relevant:

- My controller is an original Xbox controller, not a 360 controller. XNA games on Windows apparently only work with Xbox360 controllers because they use xinput rather than direct input, see eg [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums//showthread.php?t=2061391).
- My controller works (almost) properly with MonoGame trunk samples, but Bastion uses a modified MonoGame and crashes when run against trunk, so I can't add debugging to see where the problem is.
- Bug can also be reproduced with a Xbox 360 wired controller.

Comment: I have the same issue with a 360 controller, precise 64 bit

Comment: Same here... :(

Comment: Same here.

(huh, there is a character minimum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest package from the Software Centre.

Answer (score 1):

SuperGiant Games has not included joystick support for the linux release. Perhaps in a later update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the qjoypad to do joystick to keyboard emulation:

http://www.playdeb.net/updates/ubuntu/12.04/?q=qjoypad

You need to install the playdeb ppa's to get it to show up in the software centre, all of the instructions are on the playdeb site. it works awesome.